# Assigned drive letters vary on WIN 7/ WIN 10 dual boot

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, multi-boot, drive-letter

I recently created a dual boot system with WIN 7 & WIN 10  (both operating systems are on separate physical drives), but have noticed that the drive letters that are assigned to the various physical drives/partitions are different in each operating system. This causes a bit of headache when dealing with linking directories and shortcuts.

I have several questions related to this phenomenon:

1 - How does this variance occur between both operating systems?

2 - Is it possible to sync both operating systems so that they each assign the same drive letter(s) to the same physical drives/partitions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Windows recognizes drives by VolumeUUID, I guess on different OS UUIDs come in different arrangements by default.
2. Just arrange letters manually on one of systems.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Problem is they both have all their application & app data directories on C: drive. How to resolve this without complete system mayhem. ??

Comment: Do I get it right? 
You have windows 1 that has system drive on C, and windows 2 that is on the same partition, but labeled it as D?
maybe subst C:\ d:\ could help?

Comment: Impossible. The boot is always C.

Comment: Google "windows installed to drive d" and see how often magic happens ;) Had this thing once myself.
------
Could you please post disk manager screenshots of every system?